# Turn off CSS image path correction in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, rad

I have RAD 7.5 and when modifying CSS files, RAD "auto-corrects" image paths "on save".  I haven't found a way to turn that off but I don't want to keep this behavior.

The issue here is that let's say I have css like this:

```
.someClass {
   background: (images/someImage.gif);
}
```

When I save the file while in CSS design mode in RAD, the file will try to automatically change the image path to something like:

```
.someClass {
   background: (root/WEBAPPLICATION/images/someImage.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RAD, Goto Windows > Preferences > webtools > links.

1. In the right side > under defualt link path you have 2 options
2. Relative to document Directory
3. Relative to document Root directory.

I guess you need to select option 1.

Comment: For me this is in Windows, Preferences, Page Design, Links but this is the correct answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this problem that solves what I was trying to do.

I added a File Association to *.css files in Window...Preferences...Editors...File Associations.  Add *.css file type, and select "Text Editor" in the Associated Editor.
Then select "Default" to make this the default editor.

This will open css files as plain text, and not use the automatic update of image paths.